# Automate variable creation from a df with labels in R

Tags: r, loops, variables, character

I am trying to automate variable creation from a separate df of codes and labels.

I have a dataframe with a character variable that consists of codes like `'JS123B071','JS3243C093'` etc. There is no logical order of the codes in this string. In a separate dataframe I have the labels that come with the codes, e.g.: `'JS123B071', name1, 'JS3243C093', name2`

What I have is:

| id | codelist |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'JS123B071' |
| 2 | JS3243C093','JS123B071' |
| 3 | JS123B071' JS3243C093' |

What I want is:

| id | codelist | name1 | name2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'JS123B071' | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 'JS3243C093','JS123B071' | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | NA, NA, 'JS123B071', NA, 'JS3243C093' | 1 | 1 |

So I want to create a new variable per label based on the presence of the specific code in the string. I use the following code for this:

```
vec <- 'JS123B071'
df$name1 <- grepl(vec, df$codelist, fixed = TRUE)
df$name1 <- as.numeric(df$name1)

vec2 <- 'JS3243C093'
df$name2 <- grepl(vec2, df$codelist, fixed = TRUE)
df$name2 <- as.numeric(df$name2)
```

However, I now pick the codes and labels by hand. But since I have thousands of codes and labels I would like to automate this process. Is there a way I can do this with a for loop?

Comment: You mean you'd like a variable called the value of `df$name1` in this case? Probably a bad idea, instead just use a list: `vars <- list(); vars[[df$name1]] <- vec` etc.

Comment: @dash2 Thank you for your comment! I want for each code and for each observation a 1 if the code is present in the character string and a 0 if not. To be able to interpreted the new variable later I want the label as variable name.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the values that you want to check in a vector and use `sapply` to check each one of them with `grepl`.

```
vec <- c('JS123B071', 'JS3243C093')
result <- cbind(df, sapply(vec, function(x) as.integer(grepl(x, df$codelist))))
result

#  id             codelist JS123B071 JS3243C093
#1  1            JS123B071         1          0
#2  2 JS3243C093,JS123B071         1          1
#3  3 JS123B071,JS3243C093         1          1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works! 
Is there also a way to convert the variable names based on the labels?

Comment: If the labels are stored in variable `lab` (example - `lab <- c('name1', 'name2')`). You can change the column names by `names(result)[-(1:2)] <- lab `

Comment: Thank you! I have more columns in the df so the first names are overwritten now but I think I can figure that out.